# business and team trial users

Tags: grammaticality, attributive-nouns, conjunction-reduction

I'm talking about business development of a software.

The software can be used by one individual. But it is better, in terms of business model, to have teams or companies who can install the software on all their collaborators' machines.

So is it correct to say "We will develop more business and team trial users"?

Comment: Not all grammatical sentences are happy ones.

Comment: Use "acquire", "cultivate", "promote", "grow",  or "nurture" instead.

Comment: @banuyayi `We will grow more business and team trial users`?

Comment: You can use it. Q.  Will we grow more business and team trial users? A. Sure, we will grow more business and team trial users. If you don't like it, don't use it. What have you decided on (choice of word) ?

Comment: @banuyayi What about `We will grow more businesses and teams who can try our software`?

Comment: I am writing as an answer, sentences with a few new words. You can also use the above words if like these words better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences with my choice of words would be

> We will **bring in** more businesses and team trial users.
>
> We will **engender** more businesses and team trial users.
>
> We will **realise** more businesses and team trial users.
>
> We will **acquire** more businesses and team trial users.

[Realise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realise):(Merriam-Webster Dictionary) to bring into concrete existence

[Engender](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engender):(Merriam-Webster Dictionary) to cause to exist or to develop

Comment: Thank you. May I say "We will bring in more businesses and teams who can try our software"?

Comment: @SoftTimur. Yes that is correct construction and adequate.